# Import android.content.Intents

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm accessing built-in camera in google glass and I get the code here: [google glass camera](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera). My problem is I didn't know how to properly import Intents as it is needed for getting the file path. Or do I need to update by API level or what? Please let me know what to do.

This is the line on getting the file path

```
String thumbnailPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);
```

This is the library i need but i don't know what's happening:

```
import android.content.Intents;
```

Any help will be much appreiated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Intents` class you're talking about is from the [com.google.android.glass.content](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/content/Intents) package.